# Whats the correct way to measure a git blob object size

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am measuring git blobs sizes with

```sh
fileSizeThreshold=2^19
git rev-list --objects --all \
| git cat-file --batch-check='"%(objecttype)","%(objectname)",%(objectsize),%(objectsize:disk),"%(rest)"' \
| sed -n 's/^"blob",//p' \
| awk -F',' '$2'">= ${fileSizeThreshold}" \
| sort -t "," --numeric-sort --key=2 > ${outDir}/largeBlobs
```

Which gives me all blobs greater than 512kb.
I am wondering which size is the correct one to consider when thinking about putting this file (its path pattern...) in the Git Large Files Storage (LFS).

Is it `%(objectsize)` or `%(objectsize:disk)`?

Because `%(objectsize:disk)` reports some strange sizes (the bold one):

- "0901797d58f6916cad4ef4fd581d8254596bdd19", *722013b*, **105b**

In the caveat section of [git cat-file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file), there is some note about that, which I dont understand.

Considering LFS, one should look at the `objectsize:disk` supposedly because that is the space used for this blob...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at `%(objectsize)`.

---

When git stores blobs, it may store them either as flat objects, or as packed objects.

1. when storing flat objects, git still compresses the content, so the `%(objectsize:disk)` will reflect the compressed size of the blob ;
2. when packing blobs together, git may chosse to store `blob2` next to `blob1` using only its diff ;
   in that case : the `disksize` for `blob1` would be the compressed size of the blob, and the `disksize` for `blob2` would be the compressed size of *its diff with `blob1`*

The CAVEAT section mentions that some blobs may have very low reported `disksize` because *only their diff* is reported.

Comment: Perfect answer!